# CNAME not working in IE but works in Firefox for cloudapp

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have a custom domain `mydomain.net` with a CNAME pointing to my Azure Cloud Service at `myapp.cloudapp.net`.  When I enter my custom domain in Firefox it takes me to the azure cloud service and I correctly see my custom domain in the brower location bar.  However, **when I enter the same custom domain in Internet Explorer** (v9) the cloud service loads but **my custom domain isn't displayed** and I see the `myapp.cloudapp.net` address instead.

Do I need to do anything else on my custom domain or app?  I followed the link here and is says the forwarding should be invisible: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/#access-app

Comment: do you use `CNAME` or a `domain forwarding` ? The article you refer is about `CNAME` and not `domain forwarding`! What you face is most probably domain caching issue for IE. Try deleting all IE caches, wait another couple of hours and try again. There are no issues with `CNAME` and `A` DNS Records with Azure!

Comment: care to share the actual domain so we can help troubleshooting?

Comment: @astaykov Using CNAME and tried flushing dns but never suspected the regular IE cache, needless to say I cleared it and the issue was fixed, thanks so much!  If you add this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use `CNAME` or a `domain forwarding`?

The article you refer is about `CNAME` and not `domain forwarding` (which is different thing).

What you face is most probably domain caching issue for IE. Try deleting all IE caches, wait another couple of hours and try again. There are no issues with `CNAME` and `A` DNS Records with Azure.